# How can I read OL Chiki characters on Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, fonts

[OL Chiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ol_Chiki_alphabet) characters are not displaying on Android phone whose Unicode range is [1C50-1C7F] .

I know of only two processes to display such characters:

- By installing OL Chiki Unicode font. But my Android phone does not support font installation.
- By rooting the phone for installing fonts. But I do not want to root.

So, how can I install these Unicode, or how to read or display these Unicode characters on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Not all android mobile handsets support Ol Chiki, may I know which brand & model phone you are using, and whether you want to see the menu in Ol Chiki or just want to write in Ol Chiki.

If you just want to see the menu, try out [this video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-BmCpiZ_lk) & if you want to type in Ol Chiki, visit [this site](http://olchikidr.blogspot.in/2015/07/android-re-olchiki-typing.html) for fonts download search on google.

Note : By implementing these steps not all locations may show Ol Chiki as some are system driven & which cannot be override by these methods.

Answer (score -1):

If your device is rooted, you can install [Santali Ol-Chiki Font](https://sourceforge.net/projects/santaliolchiki/) (a Unicode font).

Comment: Not a bad idea, but how to achieve that? Which steps are required to install the font – assuming the device is already rooted?